Unsellable token that is transferable
Made the mistake of getting a small amount of an unsellable token on Uniswap. Here is the contract: 0xDa2E903b0B67F30BF26bD3464f9EE1a383BbbE5F
There is still plenty of liquidity in this token.
Uniswap won't allow me to sell "Transaction expected to fail", but the coins are transferable as I had no problem sending them to another Metamask wallet.
Panckakeswap shows liquidity too low and Metamask fails to find quotes.
Does anyone have any ideas? I get I've been scammed, but from reading, the fact the coins are transferrable between wallets gives me some hope.

Typical scam contract. The pool likely have some code to allow buying the token, but prevent anyone but the owner to sell it.
